# GitLab run pipeline only manually and not automatically

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My GitLab pipelines execute automatically on every push, I want to manually run pipeline and not on every push.

Pipeline docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules

I tried this in
**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - when: manual    # Error: workflow:rules:rule when unknown value: manual
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should specify a condition that tells Gitlab to not run the pipeline specifically on push events like so:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never  # Prevent pipeline run for push event
    - when: always # Run pipeline for all other cases
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is the solution I cam up with:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

This specifies that it will only run if you click the "Run Pipeline" button in the web UI. In all other cases it will not be triggered.

Comment: This one works, push does not work

Comment: This does not allow creating a manual pipeline for merge requests. It seems that if you want manual pipelines for merge requests, there's no solution for that using `workflow`.

Answer (score 18):

We can define your jobs to be only executed on Gitlab.
The web option is used for pipelines created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI, from the project's CI/CD > Pipelines section.

```
only:
   - web
```

Answer (score -4):

the `when` section should not be within `rules`

```
workflow:
  when: manual
```

Comment: Inside `workflow:rules` is [exactly where it goes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#workflowrules), but "when, can only be always or never when used with workflow."

Comment: you don't have to put it within `rules`, manual jobs exist without it. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually

Comment: You do when in `workflow`. Notice the top example in your like has it in a "job" called `deploy_prod`, not in `workflow`.